# Quickest way to get ID and Name of all fields in single go

Tags: browser-automation, c#, coded-ui-tests

Currently, I am using the traditional way i.e. 'Inspect Element' (or Firebug or IE Developer) for getting value of ID and Name attributes of any field present over page for which I am creating test cases. But, it is sometimes very time consuming especially when there are 100s of fields over a page/form. Sometimes, I use the record method abd then getting these attributes from the recorded test cases (but this too is a kind of work around).

Is there any quick way of getting ID and Name attributes of all fields (like TextBox, Dropdowns, CheckBox etc.) present on a web application page in one go.

Comment: Maybe write a code to capture elements by tag name into a list. Then traverse inside a For loop to print the attribute with the value.

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what I am looking for but will definitely try it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using CodedUI for this I would write something like this.

```
public static void GetAllElements(BrowserWindow bw)
{
var a = bw.GetChildren().Where(x => x.GetProperty("TagName").ToString() == "TD");
            foreach (var control in a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(control.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(control.GetProperty("Id"));
            }
}
```

Also if you are interested in saving time while hand coding make as many generic methods if you can

```
public static void ClickHtmlButton(string buttonidentifierType, string buttonIdentifier)
{
    var button = new HtmlButton(bw);
    if buttonidentifierType == "ID"
    {
        button.SearchProperties.Add("Id", buttonIdentifier);
    }
    if buttonidentifierType == "InnerText"
    {
        button.SearchProperties.Add("InnerText", buttonIdentifier);
    }
    Mouse.Click(button);
}
```

Comment: I tried the same but it seems not working, using the same code throws this error 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where'. But you gave me the right direction so I modified your code and it worked correctly :)

Comment: Add the linq reference

Comment: I tried with that too earlier, but I made a silly mistake of adding 'using System.Xml.Linq; instead of 'using System.Linq'. Now your solution too worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not in one go, but one list per element type, using `driver.FindElement(By.TagName("tag"))` http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp (as @ilm correctly suggested)